# Postgres consecutive time intervals

Tags: sql, postgresql, time, intervals

The table:

```
timestamp
---------------------
2018-01-15 14:31:23
2018-01-15 14:31:25
2018-01-15 14:31:26
2018-01-15 14:31:28
2018-01-15 14:31:29
2018-01-15 14:31:30
2018-01-15 14:31:35
```

It would be really helpful if someone shows how to get consecutive time intervals using sql. Consequent means that it has seconds followed one by one, if there is a gap in more than 1 second it is not consequent, and should be counted as separate interval.

The following is expected result:

```
result
--------
1
2
3
1
```

Comment: Not writing your query for you. Show some own attempt! Until you do that and ask a *precise* question: VTC as too broad.

Comment: The question is out of the context, it is a product of some work before, I am not able to share the whole task, the thing is at that point I have no idea how to do it, that is why I am here and asking for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see.  You can use `row_number()` trick for this:

```
select grp, count(*)
from (select t.*, 
             (time_stamp - row_number() over (order by timestamp) * interval '1 second') as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by grp
order by min(timestamp);
```

The idea is to subtract a sequence of numbers from the timestamp.  Timestamps that are in a sequence will all end up with the same value.  That appears to be the groups that you want.

Comment: Just a warning, this query will not work if you have too many entries in the database. It will return an error with `timestamp out of range` since you will subtract a large integer from the `time_stamp` and timestamps have a lower bound.